# Подскажите, почему не срабатывает условие if? (css, php)

Tags: php, css

Вот код:

```
foreach ($manga as $key => $item) {
    $glavs .= '<li><a href="?t='.$item["tom"].'&g='.$item["glava"].'&p=1">Том '.$item["tom"].' - Глава '.$item["glava"].'</a></li>';
    $prev = $manga[$key - 1];
    if(($item["glava"]) == $glava)  $prevGlava = $prev["glava"]; 
} 
$tomNav = ($prevGlava == $lastGlavaPredTom) ? $tom-1 : $tom;

$page = ($page_source > 1) ? $page_source-1 : 1;
$tom_next =($lastGlava==$glava)?$tom+1:$tom;

if($prevGlava == 0)  $page_prev == '.theme_dark_ .prev_nav {visibility: hidden;}';


$glava_prev = $params[1].'.html?t='.$tomNav.'&g='.$prevGlava.'&p=1';
```

Не срабатывает условие if($prevGlava == 0)  $page_prev == '.theme_dark_ .prev_nav {visibility: hidden;}';. Пробовал echo $prevGlava, показывает 0, но условие не работает. Стили пробовал оборачивать в теги `<style></style>`, тоже ничего не вышло. Как правильно написать эту строку?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете двойное равно внутри if, поэтому в переменную ничего не присваевается

```
$page_prev = '.theme_dark_ .prev_nav {visibility: hidden;}';
```

Comment: Попробовал, но все равно не работает. Но спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо оператора присваивания `=` вы используете оператор сравнения `==`) в блоке `if`.

Comment: так а что ещё нужно использовать в блоке if для того, чтобы сравнить переменную с нулём?

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что Вы говорили не о том куске кода, о котором я подумал)